# AngularJS ng-repeat is creating three empty rows when filling table with JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I found two other issues posted here experiencing a similar problem, but I'm fairly certain that my problem is not related to  tags and instead an issue with the ng-repeat function in Angular.

I am using a loop to create the HTML string which can be used to fill all the table data.

So far, It is working as expected except for one detail. Each time my loop iterates the ng-repeat creates 3 empty rows before displaying the actual data.

Here's the controller.js

```
var ngApp = angular.module('ng-app', []);
ngApp.controller('repoCntrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.commitsData = function(){
     $http.get('https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/battlemidget/python-salesforce/commits')
          .success(function(data){
              $scope.commitArray = data;
     });
  }
  $scope.commitsData();
});
```

And here's my index.html

```
<h3>Public activity in battlemidget's python-salesforce repository</h3>

<table id="mytable" border="1" class="table table-striped"> 
  <tr>
    <th>Commits</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
    <th>Parent<br>Branch(es)</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Username</th>
  </tr>
    <div id="tblContents"></div>                   
</table>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
    var tString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        tString += "<tr ng-repeat=\"commit in commitArray\">";
        tString += "<td>{{commit["+i+"].hash.substr(0,6)}}</td>";
        tString += "<td>{{commit["+i+"].message}}</td>";
        tString += "<td>";
            tString += "<p> {{commit["+i+"].parents[0].hash.substr(0,6)}}<br>"
                         + "{{commit["+i+"].parents[1].hash.substr(0,6)}}</p>";
        tString += "</td>";
        tString += "<td>{{commit["+i+"].date.substr(0,10)}}</td>";
        tString += "<td>{{commit["+i+"].author.raw}}</td>";
        tString += "</tr>";
    }
    $("#mytable").append(tString);

</script>
```

I'm a newb to web development and this is my first serious project incorporating an API, using AngularJS, etc. Sorry I've I've done anything here that goes against standard conventions. Here's a picture showing the 3 empty rows that I believe ng-repeat is inserting. I would like to know what is causing this and how I can fix it. Thanks so much. (Hope this isn't too much code). 
Here's an image displaying the empty rows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atejf.png

Comment: **Revised Question here:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416048/angularjs-ng-repeat-creating-three-empty-rows-whien-populating-table-ng-repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure AngularJS SOLUTION:

```js
var ngApp = angular.module('ng-app', []);
ngApp.controller('repoCntrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.searchFilter = null;
  $scope.commitsArray = [];

  $scope.searchFilter = function(commit) {
    var keyword = new RegExp($scope.commitFilter, 'i');
    return !$scope.commitFilter || keyword.test(commit.hash) || keyword.test(commit.date) || keyword.test(commit.author);
  };

  $scope.commitsData = function() {
    $http.get('https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/battlemidget/python-salesforce/commits')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.commitsArray = data;
      });
  }
  $scope.commitsData();

  $scope.commitsArray2 = [];
  $scope.commitsData2 = function() {
    $http.get('https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/battlemidget/python-salesforce/commits/?page=2')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.commitsArray2 = data;
      });
  }
  $scope.commitsData2();

  $scope.commitsArray3 = [];
  $scope.commitsData3 = function() {
    $http.get('https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/battlemidget/python-salesforce/commits/?page=3')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.commitsArray3 = data;
      });
  }
  $scope.commitsData3();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ng-app">

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="repoCntrl">
  <h3>Public activity in battlemidget's python-salesforce repository</h3>

  <label>Search:
    <input type="text" ng-model="commitFilter" placeholder="" />
  </label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table border="1" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Commits</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
      <th>Parent
        <br>Branch(es)</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="commit in commitsArray.values | filter: searchFilter">
      <td align="center">{{commit.hash.substr(0,6)}}</td>
      <td>{{commit.message}}</td>
      <td>
        <p align="center" ng-repeat="parent in commit.parents">
          {{parent.hash.substr(0,6)}}
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="100" align="center">{{commit.date.substr(0,10)}}</td>
      <td>{{commit.author.raw}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="commit in commitsArray2.values | filter: searchFilter">
      <td align="center">{{commit.hash.substr(0,6)}}</td>
      <td>{{commit.message}}</td>
      <td>
        <p align="center" ng-repeat="parent in commit.parents">
          {{parent.hash.substr(0,6)}}
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="100" align="center">{{commit.date.substr(0,10)}}</td>
      <td>{{commit.author.raw}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="commit in commitsArray3.values | filter: searchFilter">
      <td align="center">{{commit.hash.substr(0,6)}}</td>
      <td>{{commit.message}}</td>
      <td>
        <p align="center" ng-repeat="parent in commit.parents">
          {{parent.hash.substr(0,6)}}
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="100" align="center">{{commit.date.substr(0,10)}}</td>
      <td>{{commit.author.raw}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Ideally this should automatically check for additional pages of JSON data and load them without using hardcoded page references for the http.get

Answer (score 1):

Either chose angular or jquery but not both. What you're trying to do in jquery *can*, and *should* be done the Angular way if you're in an angular project. I'm totally confused by your title because you say ng-repeat but you're not using an ng-repeat, you're using a forloop and some voodoo jquery magic.

Try something like this:

```
    var ngApp = angular.module('ng-app', []);
    ngApp.controller('repoCntrl', function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.commitArray = [];          
       $scope.commitsData = function(){
         //when you get the chance, move this get call to a factory or service
         $http.get('https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/battlemidget/python-salesforce/commits')
              .success(function(data){
                  $scope.commitArray = data;
           });
         }
         $scope.commitsData();

    });
```

Then in your view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="thing in commitArray">
   {{some property of thing, the ith element of commit array}}
</tr>
```

Point is, read up on  ng-repeats. You can use them to loop through $scope objects. Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: That's why I initially started using angular. Never was able to get the ng-repeat to actually fill the table with all available data. Should've tackled this issue earlier.